# GIF doesn't display on Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, android-layout, gif, samsung-mobile

I have problem with displaying GIF on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.1.1) in my app. Everything is fine on Galaxy Nexus 7 emulator and others.
Here is my source code:

```
public class ShouldersEx1 extends Activity {

View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    view = findViewById(R.id.image_arms_ex1);

    setContentView(R.layout.shoulders_ex1);
}
```

}

```
public class GIFView extends View {
private Movie movie;
private long moviestart;

public GIFView(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context);
    movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("barki1.gif"));
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException {
    super(context, attrs);
    movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("barki1.gif"));
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) throws IOException {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("barki1.gif"));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (moviestart == 0)
        moviestart = now;
    int relTime;
    relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
    movie.setTime(relTime);
    movie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    this.invalidate();
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.personaltrainer.utils.GIFView
    android:id="@+id/image_arms_ex1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" >
</com.personaltrainer.utils.GIFView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tresc_informacje"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/shoulders_ex1"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
```

What can be wrong?
Please notice that on every screen I have following error:

```
01-04 02:12:06.250: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29691): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I know there is no workaround for it. Here is an officially reported issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

GIF doesn't work on Android 4.1 and newer, despite the fact that on the Android emulator it works on every Android version.

Possible solutions I see:

- wait for Android developers to resolve this issue
- split every GIF into separate frames and "manually" change it every 200 ms or similar